# Complex JOIN: 2 tables, 3 key fields, match and maintain all records needed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm struggling to work out how to join a couple of tables to get a certain result in a query.

I've got 2 tables:

1. A `[T_Prog]` table that has all possible `ID1` & `ID2` records with the amount of
   `PRGCASH` for each record against its respective `MONTHNUMBER`.
2. A `[T_ALS]` table that contains a proportion of all possible `ID1` & `ID2` records with the `ALSCASH` for each of
   those records against its respective `MONTHNUMBER`.

What I want to do is bring the `PRGCASH` and `ALSCASH` fields into a single query, matched appropriately to their respective `ID1`, `ID2` and `MONTHNUMBER` fields.

The uniqueness of a record in each table is a combination of `ID1`, `ID2` and `MONTHNUMBER` fields.

The problem I have is that the `[T_ALS]` table contains more entries on `MONTHNUMBER` against each unique `ID1` and `ID2` combination than it does in the `[T_Prog]` table.

So if I do it this way...

```sql
SELECT [T_Prog].ID1, [T_Prog].ID2, [T_Prog].MONTHNUMBER, [T_Prog].PRGCASH, [T_ALS].ALSCASH
FROM [T_Prog] 
LEFT JOIN [T_ALS] ON ([T_Prog].ID1 = [T_ALS].ID1) AND ([T_Prog].ID2 = [T_ALS].ID2) AND ([T_Prog].MONTHNUMBER = [T_ALS].MONTHNUMBER)
```

...I get all possible records, but any additional records from `[T_ALS]` on `MONTHNUMBER` will be lost as the `[T_Prog]` table does not have an equivalent record.

If I do it this way...

```sql
SELECT [T_ALS].ID1, [T_ALS].ID2, [T_ALS].MONTHNUMBER, [T_Prog].PRGCASH, [T_ALS].ALSCASH
FROM [T_ALS] 
LEFT JOIN [T_Prog] ON ([T_ALS].ID1 = [T_Prog].ID1) AND ([T_ALS].ID2 = [T_Prog].ID2) AND ([T_ALS].MONTHNUMBER = [T_Prog].MONTHNUMBER)
```

...I won't get all possible records as the `[T_ALS]` table contains only a proportion of all possible records.

Here's a illustration of the 2 tables with example data and the final query table I'm trying to achieve:

`Prog` table:

```
|[ID1]|[ID2]|[MONTHNUMBER]|[PRGCASH]|
|  1  |  A  |      1      |   600   |
|  1  |  B  |      1      |   500   |
```

`ALS` table:

```
|[ID1]|[ID2]|[MONTHNUMBER]|[ALSCASH]|
|  1  |  A  |      1      |   100   |
|  1  |  A  |      2      |   100   |
|  1  |  A  |      3      |   100   |
```

Ideal Result:

```
|[ID1]|[ID2]|[MONTHNUMBER]|[PRGCASH]|[ALSCASH]|
|  1  |  A  |      1      |   600   |   100   |
|  1  |  A  |      2      |         |   100   |
|  1  |  A  |      3      |         |   100   |
|  1  |  B  |      1      |   500   |         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query, tested with Access 2007, returns the result set you want.

```sql
SELECT
    p1.ID1,
    p1.ID2,
    p1.MONTHNUMBER,
    p1.PRGCASH,
    a1.ALSCASH
FROM
    T_Prog AS p1
    LEFT JOIN T_ALS AS a1
    ON
            p1.MONTHNUMBER = a1.MONTHNUMBER
        AND p1.ID2 = a1.ID2
        AND p1.ID1 = a1.ID1
UNION
SELECT
    a2.ID1,
    a2.ID2,
    a2.MONTHNUMBER,
    p2.PRGCASH,
    a2.ALSCASH
FROM
    T_ALS AS a2
    LEFT JOIN T_Prog AS p2
    ON
            a2.MONTHNUMBER = p2.MONTHNUMBER
        AND a2.ID2 = p2.ID2
        AND a2.ID1 = p2.ID1;
```

Comment: ah, so `UNION` would give me the best of both worlds. Works great. Thanks again, @HansUp.

Comment: You're welcome.  It seemed to me you needed a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which Access doesn't support, but union-ing those 2 result sets gives you what you need anyway.  Thanks for providing sample data and your desired output --- that made your question easier for me to answer.